# Fullcalendar change prompt instead popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have problem with change adding events with prompt instead popup in my fullcalendar. I have already tryed some solutions from SO example: [Full Calendar Add event not via promot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827975/full-calendar-add-event-not-via-promot)?

This solution working me now, but only onece!
When I click to calendar there is working popup, event is stored into my database. But when I try to add next event with click there is still text from previous event, and when I try to change and add next event with submit button, nothings happend. Next event is not possible to add, only after refresh website.

Anyway this is my code with popup:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        aspectRatio: 1.45,
        droppable: true,
        weekend: true,
        firstHour: 7,
        columnFormat: {
          month: 'dddd',    
          week: 'ddd, dS', 
          day: 'dddd, MMM dS'
       },
        header: {
            right: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
       },
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
              try {
                  setTimeline();
              } catch(err) {}
       },          
        agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
                '': 'h(:mm)t',
        drop: function (date, allDay) {
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.end = new Date(date.getDate()+2);
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(copiedEventObject.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(copiedEventObject.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
                    data: 'title=' + copiedEventObject.title + '&start=' +start + '&end=' +end + "&backgroundColor=" + copiedEventObject.backgroundColor + '&creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION["uid"]); ?>',
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                });
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        firstDay: 1,
        handleWindowResize: true,
        dragOpacity: 0.7,
        allDayDefault: false,
        events: "<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/fullcalendar/events.php?creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION['uid']); ?>",
        timeFormat:  'HH:mm { - HH:mm}',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            $(".popup").show();
            $(".submitForm").click(function(){
                var title = $(".title").val();
                if (title) {
                    start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
                        data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end +  '&creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION["uid"]); ?>',
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (json) {
                            console.log(json);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        }
                    });
                 console.log("start " + start + " end " + end);
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                $(".popup").hide();
            });
            $(".exit").click(function(){
             // clear all info, unselect events and...
              $(".popup").hide();
            });
        },
        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
            start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                         console.log(response);
                  }
            });
        },
        eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            if (confirm("Really delete event " + event.title + "with id " + event.id + "?") ) {
               $.ajax({
                url:   "<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/fullcalendar/delete_event.php",
                data: 'eid='+event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                      console.log(response); 
                      calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                  }
                });
            }
        },
        eventResize: function (event) {
            start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                      console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()),
            backgroundColor : $.trim($(this).attr('bgc'))
        };
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true, 
            revertDuration: 0
        });
    });
});
```

**My html:**

```
<div class="popup" style="display:none; position:fixed; top:25%; left:25%; background-color:white;">
  <input class"title" type="text" size="26" />
  <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="submitFrom">submit</a>&emsp;
  <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="exit">cancel</a>
</div>
```

I will very gratefull for any help.
thanks a lot !!!!!
  
  submit 
  cancel

---

Comment: Nobody help me ? I have stil problem with this ...

Comment: Do you have the code without the prompt, but with a custom form popup? That may be more useful, as we can see what you tried... Here's a fiddle for you to use, if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/Nw3fL/

Comment: Very thank you I have stored data into database but event is stored only once!! Please check my edited code.

Comment: And next issue when I click to input in popup, event in calendar is hide, will show only after submit popup.... Is there way for keep event always visible? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3fL/2/
The `.popup` div is now showing, and your click event is registered.

The problems:

1. There was a syntax error in your updated code because you didn't close the function bound to `$('.submitForm')`'s click event
2. 'submitForm' was spelled wrong in the Html
3. The text input's class attribute didn't have an equal sign before its value (`class"title"`)

I'm going to reiterate my suggestion of using the browser console for debugging. It's really important to know your tools :).

#### original answer

You have a syntax error (x2) where you are attempting to print a php session variable within a string:

`'&creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION['uid']); ?>'`

The single quote before `uid` is being parsed as the ending quote of the string "&creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION[".

Instead, use two different types of quotes for the outside string vs. the inside string (either will work):

```
'&creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION["uid"]); ?>'
 // or 
"&creator=<?php print_r($_SESSION['uid']); ?>"
```

**Next time**, you can use the [browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to view any JS errors.

Comment: Anyway thanks for opinion. Have you any idea how Can I change prompt instead popup ? Thanks a lot